# Counting and comparing rows for same values in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to compare two columns of different sizes and count the number of rows in the two columns that are a match and report this in a separate cell. I have one column that is a list with the day of the month I make contact with a person say (A5:A50) and the second column consists of the days in a month from day 1 to day 31 etc. (B5:B36).

On the day I make contact with a person, I enter the name in a column and the day of the month I make the contact (that is column A5:A50). I want a formula to then count the number of people I contacted on each day of the month and report that in the second column (B5:B36) on the appropriate day of the month there.

Example, I contact 5 people on Day 1 and enter the number 1 for it being Day 1 of the month in cells A5, A6, A7. A8 and A9. Cell B5 checks all the rows in column A5:A50 and counts only the days in A5:A50 that match the number 1 for Day 1 in column B5:B36. I repeat this for cell B6 checking for Day 2 entries etc.

The end result I am looking for is a cell for each day of the month that counts the total number of people I contacted on each day of the month. The number of people I contact will vary each month. I may contact 50 people or I could contact 150 people. The days in the month however is fixed for each month.

I hope this is clear enough but please advise if clarification is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear, but if I guessed right, you can do this with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, DAY(B5))
```

You mentioned B5:B36 contains the dates for a particular month, so if B5 contains 01/09/2013 (read 1st September 2013), `DAY(B5)` will give you `1`. The formula then counts the number of times `1` appears in column `A:A` (You can change `A:A` to the range you need, e.g. `A5:A50`, but since you mentioned you can have as much as 150 people, I opted to check the whole column).

If cells `B5:B36` instead contains numbers (1, 2, 3, etc) as opposed to dates, then use

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, B5)
```